# installaling window server 2012 r2 - under partitioning disk option

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

during installation, i was prompted this screen below

[image]

I realized if i click on new, there will be 2 partitions created,

- 1 for system reserved
- 1 for window installation

and if i ignore all options (did not click on new) and just click next directly, the installation proceeds as well.

What is the difference between choosing "new"  or clicking "Next" directly ? What should be the correct way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stick to default partitioning (a single partition spanning the entire disk, with a little system-reserved partition in front of it), then both options are functionally identical.

However, if you choose "new", you can specify the size of the new partition, which could be less than the entire disk, leaving space available for additional partitions.

Comment: so if i click Next directly without doing any partitioning, the "system" reserved partition will still be created ?   -- how come i do not see the "reserved partition"  when i go into "This PC" after login.

Comment: Because by default it's not accessible; it contains OS-reserved files, which you have no need to mess with.

Comment: That partition will always be created; you can only control the size of the "main" partition (and possibly additional partitions), but the system-reserved partition will automatically be created anyway.

Comment: thanks massimo, so theoretically if i intend to just have 1 main partition, it doesn't matter if i click "new" or "Next" directly right ?

Comment: Yes, the result will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reccomended way is to choose next.  Selecting new allows you to precreate partitions.

Comment: does clicking Next directly still create the "system reserved" partition ?

Comment: Yes, that partition will always be created; you can only control the size of the "main" partition (and possibly additional partitions), but the system-reserved partition will automatically be created anyway.